# Why function not returns custom object?

Tags: javascript

I have array of objects that I iterate on.

```
tempBnt = shortcuts.find(function(shortcut){
  if(shortcut.alias.indexOf("tomatos") > 0)
    return {
      "action":entry.action,
      "tooltip": entry.tooltip,
      "id": "btn"+entry.name
    }       
});
```

When the `if` condition is true I want to return a custom object but the code above returns a single object from `shortcuts` array.

Is it possible to return a custom object from the code above? And not an object from the `shortcuts` array?

Comment: objects are made with `new in javascript`.. try that `return new {"action":entry.action,
                        "tooltip": entry.tooltip,
                        "id": "btn"+entry.name}`

Comment: @RaymondNijland No.

Comment: The callback to `find()` is supposed to return a truthy or falsy value to indicate whether the array element matches or does not match the criteria. If it returns a truthy value, it will return the value that was found in the original array. You return an object which is considered to be a truthy value.

Comment: Maybe read about `find` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find @RaymondNijland

Comment: If `shortcut.alias === 'tomatos'`, `indexOf` will return `0`.

Comment: @RaymondNijland an object literal `{}` does not require the `new` keyword.

Comment: in fact, it will simply raise a type error since the object is not a constructor

Comment: Well to mine defense i didn't do javascript in a very very very long time..

Comment: @Michael What's the basic goal? You want to return a custom object in case the array contains a shortcut with an alias that contains tomato (should be `>=0` btw)? Look into [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Comment: Also, your "custom object" has no properties from the `shortcut` object - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks for post.Can you provide example plaese?

Comment: You should add the data you're testing, and your expected output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

[`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) only returns the first element of an array where the result is `truthy`. I think you want to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find all elements matching your condition and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change the format of your data.

And `indexOf` returns a value `>= 0`, if the string is found somewhere, ans `-1` if not found. So probably fix your condition too.

```js
let shortcuts = [
  {alias: "test", action: "test", tooltip: "test", name: "test"},
  {alias: "tomatos", action: "tomatos", tooltip: "tomatos", name: "tomatos"},
  {alias: "testtomatos", action: "testtomatos", tooltip: "testtomatos", name: "testtomatos"}
];

let tempBnt = shortcuts.filter(s => s.alias.indexOf("tomatos") > -1).map(s => ({
  action: s.action,
  tooltip: s.tooltip,
  id: "btn" + s.name
}));

console.log(tempBnt);
```